# Using android's default gallery intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gallery

I know how to open uri with the android's default gallery intent, but what I dont know its how to swipe through all my images inside it, after the selected image is open.
Any suggestions ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(images.get(position)), "image/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do you have any initial code you could provide? This doesn't meet Stack Overflow's [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, when you post a question make sure it's complete with all details, including the code so far, and the issue you are trying to resolve

Comment: Android does not have a "default gallery intent". The closest thing would be an `Intent` that [uses `CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY), but it does not involve a `Uri`.

Comment: what about pressing mobile back button?

Comment: what about not to... if the user what to swipe through all his pictures... why should he go back every time

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to open uri with the android's default gallery intent

The code in your question is to view an image. Whether it opens in a "gallery" is up to the user.

Also, since it is your image, you know what the MIME type is. Use an actual MIME type, not `image/*`.

> I dont know its how to swipe through all my images inside it

There is no requirement for the activity started by this `Intent` to have any ability to "swipe through all my images inside it". Even if it does, that behavior is up to that app's developers, not you.

If you want to have control over the UI for displaying images, write that UI yourself.

Comment: Forget what i sed. I just want to heve an option to open image for preview and also swipe betwen the rest of the photos. (like in camera app or gallery app)

Comment: @TalBrodkin: Write your own UI for that. Use `ViewPager` or a `RecyclerView` for the swiping, and use `ImageView` for the images.